# MapBox in a fragment once I press back button also having a problem with permissionsManager.requestLocationPermissions(this)

Tags: java, android, fragment, mapbox, fragment-oncreateview

I am new to Java and Android Studios. I am currently trying to put the MapBox map into a fragment, and obtain my device location. It kind of worked and the map launched in a fragment as well my location was found, but once I press back button on my device map crashes and app although does not turn off but become unresponsive. The logcat message I get is "2020-05-18 12:02:46.392 28026-28125/com.example.projektas5 W/libEGL: EGLNativeWindowType 0x7d2c6f4010 ". Also, I can only get my device location by allowing the permission in phone settings, since permissionsManager.requestLocationPermissions(this) only works for the activity. If anyone could help me, it would be much appreciated. My code below:

```
public class SecondPage extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback, LocationEngineListener, PermissionsListener {


    View root;
    MapView mapView;
    private MapboxMap map;
    private PermissionsManager permissionsManager;
    private LocationEngine locationEngine;
    private LocationLayerPlugin locationLayerPlugin;
    private Location originLocation;



    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        Mapbox.getInstance(getContext(),getString(R.string.access_token));
        root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.second_page, container, false);
        mapView =(MapView) (root).findViewById(R.id.mapView);
        mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mapView.getMapAsync(this);

        return  root;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(MapboxMap mapboxMap) {
        map = mapboxMap;
        enableLocation();
    }


    private void enableLocation() {
        if (PermissionsManager.areLocationPermissionsGranted(getContext())) {
            initializeLocationEngine();
            initializeLocationLayer();
        } else {
            permissionsManager = new PermissionsManager(this);
//            permissionsManager.requestLocationPermissions(this);
        }
    }

    private void initializeLocationEngine() {
        locationEngine = new LocationEngineProvider(getContext()).obtainBestLocationEngineAvailable();
        locationEngine.setPriority(LocationEnginePriority.HIGH_ACCURACY);
        locationEngine.activate();

        Location lastLocation = locationEngine.getLastLocation();
        if (lastLocation != null) {
            originLocation = lastLocation;
            setCameraPosition(lastLocation);
        } else {
            locationEngine.addLocationEngineListener(this);
        }
    }

    private void initializeLocationLayer() {
        locationLayerPlugin = new LocationLayerPlugin(mapView, map, locationEngine);
        locationLayerPlugin.setLocationLayerEnabled(true);
        locationLayerPlugin.setCameraMode(CameraMode.TRACKING);
        locationLayerPlugin.setRenderMode(RenderMode.NORMAL);
    }

    private void setCameraPosition(Location location) {
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),
                location.getLongitude()), 13.0));
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("MissingPermission")
    public void onConnected() {
        locationEngine.requestLocationUpdates();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        if (location != null) {
            originLocation = location;
            setCameraPosition(location);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onExplanationNeeded(List<String> permissionsToExplain) {
        //Present toast or dialog. Need to do this on my own
    }

    @Override
    public void onPermissionResult(boolean granted) {
        if (granted) {
            enableLocation();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        permissionsManager.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions,grantResults);
    }



    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if (locationEngine != null) {
            locationEngine.removeLocationUpdates();

        }
        if (locationLayerPlugin != null) {
            locationLayerPlugin.onStart();
        }
        mapView.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mapView.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mapView.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (locationEngine != null) {
            locationEngine.removeLocationUpdates();
        }
        if (locationLayerPlugin != null) {
            locationLayerPlugin.onStop();
        }
        mapView.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        mapView.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        mapView.onLowMemory();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (locationEngine != null) {
            locationEngine.deactivate();
        }
        mapView.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It'll be helpful to use a Maps SDK `SupportMapFragment`
 https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/examples/show-a-users-location-on-a-fragment/ shows how to use the Mapbox Maps SDK's `LocationComponent` in a `SupportMapFragment`.

Work off of that example? If you're still getting a crash, post more of your logcat messages. Search for anything that has `Mbgl` in it or search for `FATAL`. The `"2020-05-18 12:02:46.392 28026-28125/com.example.projektas5 W/libEGL: EGLNativeWindowType 0x7d2c6f4010 ".` message isn't very helpful for figuring out what went wrong when you pressed the back button.

Answer (score 0):

langsmith thanks for your answer. I actually managed to find why the map was crashing for me, at the end of my code I had to add onDestroyView(), see below.

```
    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        if (locationEngine != null) {
            locationEngine.deactivate();
        }
//        mapView.onDestroyView();
    }
```